# How to configure ASP.NET Core 7 Web API url in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I created two projects, an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API, and an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project.

URL of my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project is

```
https://localhost:7271;http://localhost:5122.
```

Now my question is how to configure this URL in the ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project and call inside the controller. I am in learning stage. So please help me to resolve the issue.In which place we have to write the API configuration in the ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project. Thanks!

[image]

ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the API from the MVC application, you're going to need an [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) object.

You can configure such an object with a [BaseAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress). Something like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiAddress);
```

It'd probably be a good idea to pull `apiAddress` from the configuration system, since that address is going to be environment-dependent (it's not going to be `https://localhost:7271` when you deploy it to production).

Comment: But where to add the apiaddress ?In appsettings.json file ?or where to add it

Comment: @Priya If I correctly understand the description of the setup, the MVC site and the API are effectively two different systems. This means that you somehow have to tell the MVC site about the address of the API. As I wrote, you can read the address *"from the configuration system"*. The `appsettings.json` file is the most common way to do that. For other options, see [Configuration in ASP.NET Core].(https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration).